# Evaluate $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{\sin^2x}{x^2} \, dx$

Tags: complex-analysis

How to evaluate:

> $$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{\sin^2x}{x^2} \, dx$$

This is a problem in my complex variables course.
This integral is intended to be solved by contour, but I’m struggling with it.
Thanks for anyone can give me some hints!

Answer (score 0):

Well, we can write:

$$\mathscr{I}_{\space\text{n}}:=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2\left(\text{n}\cdot x\right)}{x^2}\space\text{d}x=2\cdot\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2\left(\text{n}\cdot x\right)}{x^2}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Because it is an even function.

Using [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Formal_definition), we can write:

$$\mathcal{I}_{\space\text{n}}\left(\text{s}\right):=\mathscr{L}_x\left[\frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{\sin^2\left(\text{n}\cdot x\right)}{x}\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\int_\text{s}^\infty\mathscr{L}_x\left[\frac{\sin^2\left(\text{n}\cdot x\right)}{x}\right]_{\left(\sigma\right)}\space\text{d}\sigma=$$
$$\int_\text{s}^\infty\int_\sigma^\infty\mathscr{L}_x\left[\sin^2\left(\text{n}\cdot x\right)\right]_{\left(\theta\right)}\space\text{d}\theta\space\text{d}\sigma=\int_\text{s}^\infty\int_\sigma^\infty\mathscr{L}_x\left[\frac{1-\cos\left(2x\right)}{2}\right]_{\left(\theta\right)}\space\text{d}\theta\space\text{d}\sigma=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\int_\text{s}^\infty\int_\sigma^\infty\left(\mathscr{L}_x\left[1\right]_{\left(\theta\right)}-\mathscr{L}_x\left[\cos\left(2x\right)\right]_{\left(\theta\right)}\right)\space\text{d}\theta\space\text{d}\sigma=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\int_\text{s}^\infty\int_\sigma^\infty\left(\frac{1}{\theta}-\frac{\theta}{4+\theta^2}\right)\space\text{d}\theta\space\text{d}\sigma\tag2$$

Where I used the [frequency-domain integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) property of the Laplace transform.

Now, when $\Im\left(\sigma\right)\ne0\space\vee\space\Re\left(\sigma\right)>0$:

$$\mathcal{I}_{\space\text{n}}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\int_\text{s}^\infty\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\ln\left|4+\sigma^2\right|-2\ln\left|\sigma\right|\right)\space\text{d}\sigma=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\int_\text{s}^\infty\left(\ln\left|4+\sigma^2\right|-2\ln\left|\sigma\right|\right)\space\text{d}\sigma\tag3$$